# Python re.findall() except a variable

Tags: python, regex

Haven't used regular expressions very often, I have a rare case which is described below. I am trying to use re.findall() on a command output. [used pexcept for running the command on remote host]

`root@test# cinder image-metadata-show 9a4d222b-a6f2-4ddc-a1ce-9a635335a4b4 | grep 'image_id' | cut -d '|' -f3
 46519bdf-3ae9-44e2-acce-bd1ac76fd523`

I am trying to get 46519bdf-3ae9-44e2-acce-bd1ac76fd523 using re.findall() but the problem is re.findall is matching even in the command. My final output is something as below

```
re.findall("(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)", volume_show)
output:['9a4d222b-a6f2-4ddc-a1ce-9a635335a4b4', '46519bdf-3ae9-44e2-acce-bd1ac76fd523']
```

I want to escape 9a4d222b-a6f2-4ddc-a1ce-9a635335a4b4 which is stored in a variable in my code.

ex:

```
vol_id = 9a4d222b-a6f2-4ddc-a1ce-9a635335a4b4
re.findall("(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)", volume_show) except vol_id
output = ['46519bdf-3ae9-44e2-acce-bd1ac76fd523']
```

How can I do it? I came across re.escape() and using 'negative lookahead', it not very clear how to use re.escape and re.findall() together. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: What is the value of `volume_show`?

Comment: volume_show is the string containing the child.before() [I am using pexcept]. So volume_show = "root@test# cinder image-metadata-show 9a4d222b-a6f2-4ddc-a1ce-9a635335a4b4 | grep 'image_id' | cut -d '|' -f3
 46519bdf-3ae9-44e2-acce-bd1ac76fd523"

Comment: `re.findall(r'-f3\s+(\w[\w-]*)', volume_show)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add characters to the beginning of your regular expression to match line starts and newlines.

Here's a modification of your expression that matches a line start `^` or newline character `\n` a variable amount of whitespace `\s*` and then your 4 groups of alphanumerics:

```
[\^\n]\s*(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)
```

And here's how it looks in a python session:

```
volume_show = '''root@test# cinder image-metadata-show 9a4d222b-a6f2-4ddc-a1ce-9a635335a4b4 | grep 'image_id' | cut -d '|' -f3\n 46519bdf-3ae9-44e2-acce-bd1ac76fd523\n\n'''
                                                                                                                                             
re.findall('[\^\n]\s*(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)', volume_show)                                                                                                                   

['46519bdf-3ae9-44e2-acce-bd1ac76fd523']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do some post processing? like

```
output = [x for x in output if x != vol_id]
```

Comment: Yes, I can do it. But the code is not very efficient enough in my case. Looking for something that can be done using re.findall(). Right now I am doing the post-processing itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern:

```
re.findall(r"(?!%s)(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)" % vol_id, volume_show)
```

Comment: Didn't work it only escaping the very first character.  for example re.findall("(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)", volume_show)) output is ['9a4d222b-a6f2-4ddc-a1ce-9a635335a4b4', '46519bdf-3ae9-44e2-acce-bd1ac76fd523'] where as re.findall(r"(?!%s)(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)" % vol_id, volume_show)  output is ['a4d222b-a6f2-4ddc-a1ce-9a635335a4b4', '46519bdf-3ae9-44e2-acce-bd1ac76fd523']